# PostgreSQL: how to reset config parameter?

Tags: postgresql, config

postgresql.config:
log_min_duration_statement = -1

Client A:

```
SELECT set_config('log_min_duration_statement', '30000', false);
SELECT current_setting('log_min_duration_statement');
-----
30s
```

Client B:

```
SELECT current_setting('log_min_duration_statement');
-----
-1
```

The client B changes postgresql.config:
log_min_duration_statement = 60000

```
select pg_reload_conf();
SELECT current_setting('log_min_duration_statement');
---
1 min
```

===

Ok,
How the client A can reset his setting and use the current parameter value from the postgresql.config file without connection closing?
I.e. the client A does

```
select pg_reload_conf();
```

but he still has a previously set 30s

Comment: just `reset log_min_duration_statement`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-reset.html

> RESET — restore the value of a run-time parameter to the default value

just

```
reset log_min_duration_statement
```

also https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-admin.html

> `set_config` sets the parameter setting_name to new_value. If is_local
>   is true, the new value will only apply to the current transaction. If
>   you want the new value to apply for the current session, use false
>   instead. The function corresponds to the SQL command SET.

In other words you don't need `pg_reload_config()` - because you change setting on session level only. you need reload only after modifying ponstgres.conf

same link above:

> `pg_reload_conf()`    Cause server processes to reload their
>   configuration files